# Angular ng-file-upload convert from base64 to file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried to upload and cropping using [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload).

The problem is the cropped image become base64 format instead of 'file` format.

Here is the console.log result on testing:

[image: console log]

my html:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label">Cover</label>
     <input type="file" ngf-select ng-model="category.cover" name="cover" id="cover" ngf-pattern="image/*" accept="image/*"
     ngf-max-size="512KB" class="filestyle" data-button-name="btn-danger">

     <div ngf-drop ng-model="category.cover" ngf-pattern="image/*" class="cropAreaCover">
          <img-crop image="category.cover  | ngfDataUrl" result-image="category.croppedDataUrl" ng-init="category.croppedDataUrl=''"
                              area-type="square" area-min-size="800">
           </img-crop>
      </div>
</div>
```

How can I convert the cover result (base64) to file like logo result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found it using plain javascript syntax:

```
var cover =Upload.dataUrltoBlob(category.croppedDataUrl);
cover = new File([cover], 'cover.jpg', {type:"image/jpg"});
```

Comment: that was perfect

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
<img ng-src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{logo}}"  / >
```

Comment: hi, isn't this code convert from file to base64? 

i've tried on my cover. it says invalid url.